# Unit Testing Rest API | Need to Disable Authorization| Spring Boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have developed a REST API using Spring Boot.I need to unit test POST method of REST API developed. Since i have used

> @EnableSecurity in Application.class
>   @@Authorization(authorizedGroups = {"CN=APP-XYG-Group"} in Controller

I am not able to test using Junit, since i have Enabled Security and i get 403 error , when actually i would like to test for 200 OK http status code.

I would like to disable the security checking while doing testing, Is it possible. Please find the code snippet below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ParseInput {

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testRate() throws Exception {

        //setting up input for test case
        QReq qReq= new QReq();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            qReq = objectMapper.readValue(new File("src/main/resources/input.json"), QReq.class);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error message here is " + e.getMessage());
        }

        //Executing the test case

        ResponseEntity<QResp> subject = restTemplate.postForEntity("/tax_rates/v1/quotations", qReq, QResp.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, subject.getStatusCode());
    }

}
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Testing With Spring MockMvc and SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors

You can use Spring `MockMvc` and `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors` to create a mock user with role `CN=APP-XYG-Group`.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ParseInput {

    @Mock
    private RateService rateService;

    @InjectMocks
    private RateController rateController;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRate() throws Exception {

        //setting up input for test case
        QReq qReq= new QReq();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        qReq = objectMapper.readValue(
            new File("src/main/resources/input.json"), QReq.class);

        //mocking the service to return a mock object
        when(rateService.myMethod(any(QReq.class))).thenReturn(qReq);

        //Executing the test case
        mockMvc.perform(post("/tax_rates/v1/quotations")
           .with(user("myUser").roles("CN=APP-XYG-Group"))
            .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(qReq))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());

        //To retrieve response body
        MvcResult result = 
            mockMvc.perform(post("/tax_rates/v1/quotations")
               .with(user("myUser").roles("CN=APP-XYG-Group"))
               .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(qReq))
               .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
               .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andReturn();

        String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The security configuration we use for our API is downloaded as a JAR and added to the class path. We use a common jar inside our organization. In that case, is it possible for me to disable the same.
Am a newbie to Spring and hence the doubt

Comment: Are you using any type of mock for your tests?

Comment: No ... am using simple JUnit. As a first step i want to check http status code 200 OK, which is not working because of the security related jars

Comment: I passed headers and did not use MockMvc ... My test case is passing now